# Unexplained array sort occuring in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a practice project - a Dota related mini game.

http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/MwGsd/

You are making combinations of 3 reagents to summon(invoke) a spell.

I have an array containing all possible spell combinations and another empty array which records keypresses and stores the pressed reagent in that array. **You always need 3 reagents to create a spell - the order of reagents does not matter.**

So far all works, but I'm encoutering a problem once I start comparing the inputed reagents array to the spell list array:

I'm using the following compare function:

```
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.sort().toString() === arr2.toString()
}
```

I sort the array and compare in the following function (`reagentStack` - contains the inputed reagents):

```
    function updateSpellList(reagentStack){         
        for( var spell in spellList ) {
            var compareStack = reagentStack;
                compareSpell = spellList[spell];

            console.log(spell);
            console.log('compareStack: ' + compareStack + ' / compareSpell: ' + compareSpell + ' / reagentStack: ' + reagentStack); // check this log in fiddle console
            console.log('---');

            if(compareArrays(compareStack, compareSpell)) {
                invokedSpell = spell;                   
                console.log('Invoked spell: ' + invokedSpell);
                break;
            }

        }           
    }
```

In the example fiddle ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/MwGsd/)) if you press <kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> you create a spell combination (in this case icewall).

It is comparing all ok and follows my script logic (set's `compareStack` to `reagentStack`, sorts the `compareStack` and `compareSpell` arrays and compares), but I can't understand **why does it also sort `reagentStack` array since I'm not sorting it anywhere in the whole script**?

It is not sorted on the first iteration of `for` loop, but get's sorted on second iteration and won't compare anymore correctly since now `compareStack` is getting set to a sorted `reagentStack` instead to the originally inputed.

Console log:

```
coldsnap
compareStack: quas,quas,exort / compareSpell: quas,quas,quas / reagentStack: quas,quas,exort
---
ghostwalk
compareStack: exort,quas,quas / compareSpell: quas,quas,wex / reagentStack: exort,quas,quas
```

On first loop the reagentStack is not sorted  on second loop it is already sorted - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do sort the array in question: On this line you create a reference to the very array:

```
var compareStack = reagentStack;
```

which gets then passed on to

```
if(compareArrays(compareStack, compareSpell)) {
```

where it is sorted in turn. [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) modifies the array it is applied to unlike some other operations, which just return a new modified array.

If you want a (shallow) copy of the array, use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var compareStack = reagentStack.slice(0);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MwGsd/1/)

Comment: oh, yeah that's it - didn't know that it get's passed on like that. Thanks for help!

Comment: @easwee btw I would use `JSON.stringify()` over `toString()` in the compare function. more stable in case your arrays contain `,`.